# Problems with fonts in Visual Studio, bad quality

Tags: visual-studio, fonts

Since I started using visual studio I have been having a problem with all fonts.

They just all look bad in Visual Studio, as if they have too many pixels.

In the image below, the **first line is a normal font**, as it should be. **In the second line is Visual Studio**, the same font, same size, but very ugly, it even seems to be stretched.

The only way I found to get around this is to go to other programs like Adobe XD, put the text I want and save it as an image, then I go to Visual Studio and put it as an image.

But, this is a problem, since if I want to change the text size or change the content of the text it will not be possible.

[image]

**Edit:**

In program.cs I changed the following line to true and improved it a lot:

```
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true);
```

I think it can still improve.

[image]

Comment: How and where are you using these fonts?

Comment: In Visual Studio? If so, I'm using it in labels / textboxes.

The first source of the image is from Adobe XD, which is an image, but as I said this is a problem.

I have a progress bar and on top of it is a label that updates as the progress bar grows, however using the visual studio sources it is difficult to see.

Comment: I think Microsoft's rendering engine won't beat Adobe's.

Comment: The problem is that any program I use is superior in terms of fonts, it’s not just Adobe’s.